# equivalent .sh or make file for a .BAT file

Tags: command-line, windows, makefile, batch

I bought a book yesterday on OS development however, the book is written for windows systems and this was not mentioned in the description. I need to convert a .BAT file into an equivalent shell script or makefile and don't know how to resolve one error.

this is my directory structure:

```
OsDev
--src/
----Boot.asm
----Kernel_Entry.asm
----main.c
--bin/
```

the book's source code can be found here https://github.com/TINU-2000/OS-DEV/tree/main/Beginning-OS-DEV/Entering%20c

I rewrote the .bat file to this .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

nasm src/Boot.asm -f bin -o bin\bootsect.bin
nasm src/Kernel_Entry.asm -f elf -o bin\Entry.bin

gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c src/main.c -o bin\kernel.o

ld -T NUL -o bin\Kernel.img -Ttext 0x1000 bin\Entry.bin bin\kernel.o

objcopy -O binary -j .text  bin\kernel.img bin\kernel.bin
copy /b /Y bin\bootsect.bin+bin\kernel.bin bin\os-image

qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=bin\os-image
```

but I get an error:

```
ld: cannot open linker script file NUL: No such file or directory
objcopy: 'binkernel.img': No such file
./make.sh: 11: copy: not found
```

Can someone tell me what needs to be done to make this work on ubuntu 22.04? Many thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure your script is correct; ie. I note `bin\bootsect.bin` as an output file which will be understood as `binbootsect.bin` but is that you want want?  ie. you've used the `\` or escape character so 'b` is interpreted as a special character; but `b` doesn't require that.  Directory paths contain a `/` character

Comment: this is written for windows and taken from the book - I guess I did not check thoroughly. Thanks! its true that / is needed.

Comment: In Windows directory separator for paths is `\ ` , while in Linux it is `/`. Please, correct them first.

Comment: There are a number of differences, ie. I note a `copy` that maybe intended to be a `cp` (or file copy) command rather than a specific script provided by the book/creator of the code.. I didn't look at your provide source link, but a number of such issues were apparent.   *My initial comment was based on your actual error message in that `binkernel.img` isn't found.. I just used the first item I saw as example*  (and even if `copy` is intended to be `cp`, the options weren't converted to POSIX compliant either)

Comment: If the book is "Windows"-y, then the utilities might also be windows type executables. You need to replace them to be able to run any similar script on any Linux machine. As guiverc says, 'copy' is generally 'cp' on Linux. I'm suspecting you need to read up on how the script supposed to be used, and only then a conversion or adaptation may be "clear". As it is now, any conversion isn't possible - based on just the facts above.

Comment: thanks all of you!